# Getting exception while calling WCF service from WCF service

Tags: wcf, exception, service, timeout

We are 2 WCF service A) hosted on IIS and B) hosted as Windows service.

We are using WSHttp binding

When i am calling B from A i am receiving the below error

> To prevent the service from aborting
>   idle sessions prematurely increase the
>   Receive timeout on the service
>   endpoint's binding

any idea???

Comment: Does it come wrapped in an MessageSecurityException?

Comment: typically, this means either you just have a problem with your timeout - increasing it might help - or your message size is too large and can't be handled. Can you show us the server-side config for the two services?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to watch out for here:

- When Service A calls service B, it is the web.config of service A that is being used on the client side.
- When Service A calls service B, it may be the identity of the application pool that is being used
- Are you sure that service B is running, can you call it from a client other than service A.
- Which port is Service B running on, is that port blocked in the firewall?
- Which port is Service B running on, is it the same as the IIS site? In that case you will get a crash and the service B will not be able to listen on the port

My guess is that it is probably one of the last 2